# Creating multiple Threads Using Java RecursiveTasks

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join

So I'm trying to familiarise myself with concurrent programing in java so I wrote the following code

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
        pool.invoke(new Agent());

    }
}

class thread extends RecursiveTask<Integer>{    

    thread(){
        System.out.println("Thread");
    }

    public Integer compute(){ 
        thread x = new thread();
        x.fork();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

which as far as I understand should print 'Thread' infinitely but when I run it only print 'Thread' about 20 times.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Naming your class lowercase `t` `thread` is a terrible pattern btw.  `MyRecursiveTask` would be a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thread will exit, and claim the live of the threads in the ForkJoinPool. You can see this with

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(new MyRecursiveTask());

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(Just for illustration, of course...)